# Question on convergence of Chebyshev series

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, approximation-theory, numerical-calculus, chebyshev-polynomials

I have written a script that plots some function and its truncated Chebyshev expansion in $[-1,1]$, which is given by
$$
\sum a_nT_n(x) \quad \text{with} \quad a_n = \int_{-1}^{1}T_n(x)f(x)/\sqrt{1-x^2}dx
$$

except for $a_0$, which must be divided by two. I represented different functions and for each function I considered a different number of terms in the truncated series, and I observed that the approximation at the endpoints tends to worsen as the number of terms in the truncated series increase. Why does this happen?

Comment: Chebyshev expansions are very close to Fourier series ; therefore, no surprise that the classical **Gibbs phenomenon** occurs (due to truncation) . This can occur also with other families of orthogonal polynomials ; see [here](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/250891872_The_Gibbs_phenomenon_for_series_of_orthogonal_polynomials).

Comment: @JeanMarie The paper deals with discontinuities, it considers step functions. Is expected that the same phenomenon occuts at the endpoints of the interval $[a,b]$, since for $x<$ and $x>b$ there is no convergence. At first I thought it was because, in the case of Chebychev polynomials, the weight function is $\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}$, and when $|x|$ approaches 1, then a denominator goes to 0. However, it also occurs with Legendre polynomials, which do not present this problem, although in a less obvious way.

Comment: @JeanMarie I guess the computational limitations in numeric representation also can cause some distorsion when many terms in the truncated series are considerered..

Comment: For your first comment, I agree. For yor second comment, I have some doubts that "error accumulation" for example can be influential in this case.